# Le sens de « au vif » dans la phrase « piquer l'attention de Charlotte au vif »

Tags: sens, expressions

> ... pour piquer l'attention de Charlotte **au vif**.

Je me demande si « au vif » veut dire « d'une manière directe », ou quelque chose de ce style, vu que l'expression « entrer dans le vif du sujet », par exemple, signifie le fait d'en venir au fait ou d'aller droit au but sans tourner autour du pot.

Comment: Pour info, l'expression est "piquer au vif", où "l'attention de Charlotte" est le COD qui vient compléter l'expression.

Comment: @Random I notice that you have corrected my phrasing "faire montre d'une force surhumaine". I wonder if "faire preuve de" and "faire montre de" are only interchangeable when you talk about a feeling or a personal quality, such as "faire montre/preuve d'un altruisme inhabituel"? Merci.

Comment: I've never heard "faire montre de", and I don't think you can say it in any context... the closest phrasing I see is "Montrer de la force" which is close to "faire preuve de force" for instance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le vif peut signifier **la chair à nu** (comme dans "une plaie à vif"). Dans ce sens, cela veut dire que les « ... » qui précèdent touchent au point le plus sensible ou le plus douloureux ("piquer au vif" est l'expression, comme l'a rappelé @Random).

En général, c'est un sens figuré : toucher l'amour-propre, par exemple, vexer, blesser, l'atteindre dans un domaine qui tient à coeur à l’intéressée.

Comment: "les ..." c'est pour reprendre le début de la phrase de l'OP, ou pour biper un mot ? C'est pas très clair... :)

Comment: Biper, non ! Plutôt écrire en Morse. Bien sûr, il s'agit ici de l'ellipse initiale